# CSS flex child component has to <span> child components not fitting correctly into 3x2 flex container

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

So I have a flex container that has a parent, and a div, which has 2x spans.  The container is taking the 3x2 format, but the spans seems to be pushing each other out of place. I have tried changing the display types to inline, contents, etc. but it stills seems the first span has an overflow that is forcing the second span you be pushed out. I don't quite understand what the issue is.

[Here is a link to the sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-gmo8n?file=/styled.js)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that the first span needed a `display: block` which solved the issue